# Dual nginx in one Kubernetes pod

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am doing a lab about *kubernetes* in *google cloud*, so my task is deploy two *nginx* servers in one pod, however I have a issue.

One of the pods can not starts, as PORT or IP is using buy another nginx container, I need to change it in yaml file, please give me a solution, thank you in advance

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: two-containers
spec:

  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
  - name: shared-data
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:

  - name: first-container
    image: nginx
  - name: second-container
    image: nginx

E  nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

E  2019/01/21 11:04:47 [emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

E  nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

E  2019/01/21 11:04:47 [emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

E  nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

E  2019/01/21 11:04:47 [emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

E  nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

E  2019/01/21 11:04:47 [emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

E  nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

E  2019/01/21 11:04:47 [emerg] 1#1: still could not bind()

E  nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

Answer (score 12):

In kubernetes the container in pods share single network namespace. To simplify, two container cannot listen to same port, in same pod.

So in order to two nginx container within same pod, you need to run them on different port. One nginx can run on 80 and other on 81.

So we will run `first-container` with default nginx config and for `second-container` we will be running with below config.

- default.conf

```
server {
    listen       81;
    server_name  localhost;
    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

- Create a configmap from this `default.conf`

```
kubectl create configmap nginx-conf --from-file default.conf
```

- Create a pod as following.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: two-containers
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: config
    configMap:
      name: nginx-conf
  containers:
  - name: first-container
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
  - name: second-container
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 81
    volumeMounts:
    - name: config
      mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

- Deploy the pod.
- Now exec into the pod and try to ping on `localhost:80` and `localhost:81` it will work.
  Let me know, if you need any more help in it.

Comment: why it's fully possible to do with docker-compose and impossible to do with k8s? in docker-compose we just need to map ports like `ports: ['8000:80']` for first and `ports: ['8001:80']` for second container.

Comment: yes. I have the same question as above. 
why it's so easy to do with `docker run` or `docker-compose` but not in k8s?

Comment: Docker compose still runs each container with a unique IP address and network namespace, and creates an overlay network (`default`) to wire them to each other. Notice how when you need to connect to another container in the same project you refer to it by DNS as its service name. Whereas in Kubernetes, every container in a pod shares `localhost`.

Comment: Can someone help me understand this. when we say "Two container cannot listen to same port" - are we talking about the ports Inside the containers? Since containers are isolated, Why not app run on both of them on same ports? (ie the internal port) All that matters is they shouldnt be exposed to the same port right?

Comment: Tried this and works for a multicontainer pod. 
But I tried to do this via a Deployment, with no configMap.. wondering why it does not work. In my deployment the pods were exposed with 80 and 81 port, so ideally the containers should be exposed on different ports even if internally they use the same default port 80. Trying to understand this.