# 2 containers using the same port in Kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have the same problem as the following:
[Dual nginx in one Kubernetes pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289786/dual-nginx-in-one-kubernetes-pod)

In my Kubernetes `Deployment` template, I have 2 containers that are using the same port 80.
I understand that containers within a `Pod` are actually under the same network namespace, which enables accessing another container in the `Pod` with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. 
It means containers can't use the same port.

It's very easy to achieve this with the help of `docker run` or `docker-compose`, by using `8001:80` for the first container and `8002:80` for the second container.

Is there any similar or better solution to do this in Kubernetes Pod ? Without separating these 2 containers into different Pods.

Comment: You rarely want to run multiple containers in a single pod.  That’s doubly true if they’re distinct servers using a standard port.  Split them into two separate pods.

Comment: of you understand docker-compose I would recommend you use an application called komposer. It will convert your docker-compose file to a k8s.yaml setup.

In your case it will be a service definition that you will need to create, mapping pod ports to container ports.

Comment: k8s does not have a means to set p a port forwarding the docker-compose does. Do you have a use case for running two webservers in the same pod? Why not run them in different pods? If you NEED both containers in the same pod, consider changing the port that the container service listens to.

Comment: Hi, @PatrickW 

I don't have a very firm use case, because I'm still very new to Kubernetes and the concept of a cluster.
My initial planning of the cluster is putting all my containers of the system into a pod. So that I can replicate this pod as many as I want.

But according to all the feedback that I have now, it seems like I going in the wrong direction. 
I'll review my structure and try with the suggests you all provided.

Thank you, everyone! =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically I totally agree with *@David's* and *@Patric's* comments but I decided to add to it a few more things expanding it into an answer.

> I have the same problem as the following: [Dual nginx in one Kubernetes pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289786/dual-nginx-in-one-kubernetes-pod)

And there is already a pretty good answer for that problem in a mentioned thread. From the technical point of view it provides ready solution to your particular use-case however it doesn't question the idea itself.

> It's very easy to achieve this with the help of docker run or
>   docker-compose, by using 8001:80 for the first container and 8002:80
>   for the second container.

It's also very easy to achieve in **Kubernetes**. Simply put both containers in different `Pods` and you will not have to manipulate with nginx config to make it listen on a port different than `80`. Note that those two docker containers that you mentioned don't share a single network namespace and that's why they can both listen on ports `80` which are mapped to different ports on host system (`8001` and `8002`). This is not the case with **Kubernetes** *Pods*. Read more about **microservices architecture** and especially how it is implemented on **k8s** and you'll notice that placing a few containers in a single `Pod` is really rare use case and definitely should not be applied in a case like yours. There should be a good reason to put 2 or more containers in a single `Pod`. Usually the second container has some complimentary function to the main one.

There are [3 design patterns for multi-container Pods, commonly used in **Kubernetes**](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2015/06/the-distributed-system-toolkit-patterns/): sidecar, ambassador and adapter. Very often all of them are simply referred to as **sidecar containers**.

Note that 2 or more containers coupled together in a single `Pod` in all above mentioned use cases *have totally different function*. Even if you put more than just one container in a single `Pod` (which is most common), in practice it is never a container of the same type (like two nginx servers listening on different ports in your case). They should be complimentary and there should be a good reason why they are put together, why they should start and shut down at the same time and share same network namespace. Sidecar container with a monitoring agent running in it has complimentary function to the main container which can be e.g. nginx webserver. You can read more about container design patterns in general in [this](https://techbeacon.com/enterprise-it/7-container-design-patterns-you-need-know) article.

> I don't have a very firm use case, because I'm still
>   very new to Kubernetes and the concept of a cluster.

So definitely don't go this way if you don't have particular reason for such architecture.

> My initial planning of the cluster is putting all my containers of the system
>   into a pod. So that I can replicate this pod as many as I want.

You don't need a single `Pod` to replicate it. You can have in your cluster a lot of `replicaSets` (usually managed by `Deployments`), each of them taking care of running declared number of replicas of a `Pod` of a certain kind.

> But according to all the feedback that I have now, it seems like I going
>   in the wrong direction.

Yes, this is definitely wrong direction, but it was actually already said. I'd like only to highlight why namely this direction is wrong. Such approach is totally against the idea of *microservices architecture* and this is what **Kubernetes** is designed for. Putting all your infrastructure in a single huge `Pod` and binding all your containers tightly together makes no sense. Remember that a `Pod` *is the smallest deployable unit in **Kubernetes*** and when one of its containers crashes, the whole `Pod` crashes. There is no way you can manually restart just one container in a `Pod`.

> I'll review my structure and try with the
>   suggests you all provided. Thank you, everyone! =)

This is a good idea :)

Comment: thank you! @mario.
Your answer does really make my day because you explained all of them in detail, and I benefit from it.
I have a better understanding of Kubernetes now. And I'll continue to explore more from it. 
Once again. thank you! =)
sincerely appreciate. ‍♂️

Comment: >when one of its containers crashes, the whole Pod crashes.   

That's a bit extreme. The whole pod can keep running if a container crashes; it will just get restarted. Same with liveness probe - only restarts container.

Still, this is true "There is no way you can **manually** restart just one container in a Pod."

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you need to do is specify a different [Container Port](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#containerport-v1-core) for each container in the pod. Kubernetes allows you specify the port each container exposes using this parameter in the pod definition file. You can then create services pointing to same pods but different ports.

Comment: what if you can change the port your container exposes?

Comment: apparently, pod.spec.containers[].ports[].containerPort is purely for documentation and doesn't affect anything.

Comment: No even if you use different container port you cant have two nginx containers running inside same port